# django models:how to select records from django auth_user_groups table

Tags: python, django

How can I use django models to select records from auth_user_groups table ?.

For example, you can use:

```
querySet =  User.objects.get(id=1) to retrieve the row corresponding to id=1
```

Is there any method like this to fetch data from auth_user_groups?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all groups of a user you can do this:

```
user.groups.all()
```

to get all users of a group:

```
group.user_set.all()
```

I guess this should answer your question, since there is no more information in the auth_user_groups table.

Comment: If this is the correct solution, please up-vote the answer and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you need this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
qs = Group.objects.get(id=1)
```

Comment: Thanks!!!We can query the 'Group'table as you mentioned.but,is there any way to query 'auth_user_groups' table??

Comment: "auth_user_groups" this is intermediate table between User and Group. I can help if i'll be know what is exactly your task.

Comment: I need to fetch the group_id w.r.t user_id from auth_user_groups table

Answer (score 1):

```
user = models.User.objects.get(id = 1)

all_values_from_group = Group.objects.get(user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user=User.objects.get(id=1)
group=Group.objects.get(id=1)
group_1=user.groups.get(id=group.id)
```

This returns the group entry in auth_user_groups table where user_id=1 and group_id=1.

Answer (score 0):

First get the user object,

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(id=some_user_id)
```

When we use [dir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function, you can see list of the all the available methods and attributes of the `user.groups` object.

```
>>> dir(user.groups)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slotnames__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_add_items', '_apply_rel_filters', '_build_remove_filters', '_constructor_args', '_db', '_get_queryset_methods', '_hints', '_insert', '_queryset_class', '_remove_items', '_remove_prefetched_objects', '_set_creation_counter', '_update', 'add', 'aggregate', 'all', 'annotate', 'auto_created', 'bulk_create', 'check', 'clear', 'complex_filter', 'contribute_to_class', 'core_filters', 'count', 'create', 'creation_counter', 'dates', 'datetimes', 'db', 'db_manager', 'deconstruct', 'defer', 'difference', 'distinct', 'do_not_call_in_templates', 'earliest', 'exclude', 'exists', 'explain', 'extra', 'filter', 'first', 'from_queryset', 'get', 'get_by_natural_key', 'get_or_create', 'get_prefetch_queryset', 'get_queryset', 'in_bulk', 'instance', 'intersection', 'iterator', 'last', 'latest', 'model', 'name', 'none', 'only', 'order_by', 'pk_field_names', 'prefetch_cache_name', 'prefetch_related', 'query_field_name', 'raw', 'related_val', 'remove', 'reverse', 'select_for_update', 'select_related', 'set', 'source_field', 'source_field_name', 'symmetrical', 'target_field', 'target_field_name', 'through', 'union', 'update', 'update_or_create', 'use_in_migrations', 'using', 'values', 'values_list']
```

So you can work with all the methods and attributes of the user's groups, which mean in the `auth_user_groups` table. I'll select few of them such as `set`, `add`, `remove` and `clear` for an example.

```
# you can set list of groups for the user
user.groups.set([group_list])

# you can add group one by one for the user
user.groups.add(group, group, ...)

# you can remove group one by one from the user
user.groups.remove(group, group, ...)

# you can clear all the groups which are belongs to the user
user.groups.clear()
```

Here you can refer more about [Django Authentication System](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#using-the-django-authentication-system) in the Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is to retrive the logged in users groups
in views.py

```
    users = User.objects.all()
```

then in html

```
              {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                    {% for user_group in user.groups.all %}
                        {{ user_group.name }}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
```